# Custom post view counter WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am making custom post view counter but it's not working. I have made change on working post view code but not working.

`<?php echo $td_mod_single->get_views();?>` this one is working post view counter. I have changed it to like this `<?php echo $count = rand(1,999); ?>` but it's not working.

I have replaced this `<?php echo $td_mod_single->get_views();?>` to `<?php echo $count = rand(1,999); ?>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do the rand, you don't need to count it..

```
<?php echo rand(1,999); ?>
```

This will output a random number between 1 and 999

Comment: And if you change it to the simplest it could be `<?php echo "Testing"; ?>` does it show the word 'testing'. If not then the program is not using the part of the code you are editing.